# How do I set ANT DESIGN INITIAL VALUE form from API response

Tags: javascript, antd

How do I set initialValues on ant design?
I want response.data(as shown on console.log) to be my initialValues on my Form.

### [image]
[image]
[image]

HERE IS MY OLD CODE
[image: My code][image: Form && console.log]
[image]

Comment: Please add actual code snippets instead of screenshots, so that your code can be used in the answer. Even better if you provide a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so that your issue can be reproduced and tested easily.

Answer (score 3):

The `Form` component does not **re-render** when the initial values change. So when your component mounts there is no response from the API yet and therefore the form is **initialized with empty values** (before API response is returned).

The sequence right now is like this

1. Form component mounts and you also make API request ideally in `componentDidMount`
2. It takes data from `initialValues` prop, which is empty since API response is not yet received.
3. API request completes and now you have data in state, but even if the state of your component updates, the `Form` component from Ant Design will not re-render because it already received the `initialValues` on mount.

**Solution:**
You should hide the form and ideally show a loader while the initial data is still being fetched. The code will look something like this

```
if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

else return <Form 
              form={form}
              // Rest of your component code
```